# SIP server forwarding

Tags: sip, voip, pbx

I have many SIP servers, but none of them have an external network. Can I use a server with an external network to proxy many SIP servers without an external network

Comment: I'm not an expert on this topic, so I can't provide an answer, but I would suggest you look into the concept of a 'Reverse Proxy' for SIP Servers - it seems there's information on this around the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can.

Try using opensips or asterisk as a proxy to redirect calls to nat endpoints. What you’re trying to do is basically how sip providers work

Example: Proxy example

[image]

User A is your NAT SIP Servers, Proxy is NAT/External SIP Server and B is PSTN
Gateway or PSTN/SIP Provider

In case you have no idea how to get started, here is a useful article, it covers devices but we can consider that devices and servers are endpoints, so the article is for you:
[Using SIP Devices behind NAT](https://kb.smartvox.co.uk/voip-sip/sip-devices-nat/)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a **SBC** Session-Border-Controller.
Have a nice day.